# Highlight Microsoft EXCEL spreadsheet in a certain pattern

Tags: excel

in excel I would like to highlight in a pattern with 3 colours for infinity.

Like this:

```
A1(blue), B1(red), C1(blue), D1(red) -------> goes on forever
A2(red), B2(green), C2(red), D2(green) -----> goes on forever
A3....
A4....
etc
```

Anyone know how to write a formula for this and use it in "conditional formatting?" I've tried but can't do it.

Thanks :D

Comment: Is A3 a repeat of the formatting in A1? Also, I think you may need to use vba to achieve this. I suggest looking for vba examples on here as a first step.

Comment: Actually I just figured it out. Its not infinite but good enough. I used automatic number rows. Thanks though!

Comment: God news, excellent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below 2 formulas in conditional formatting

1. for red color:

   =MOD(Column(A1),2) = 0
2. for blue color:

   =MOD(Column(A1),2) = 1

Thanks